# problem with share products on facebook

Tags: facebook, share, product

i am using facebook sharer for share products which is in my website into facebook. i tried all the ways to do this..but i don't know where is the problem.

when i am clicking the facebook icon in mysite then it redirecting to facebook and not displaying product name, product image, description of product. it cames untitled document. here is the code i was used.

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="<?=$fetpro['productname'];?>" />
<meta name="description" content="Join this bloc to help me get a deal at BBuys" />
<meta name="medium" content="medium_type" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.mysite.com/admin/product_images/<?=$fetpro['product_image']?>" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.mysite.com/details.php?pro_id=<?php echo $fetpro['auto_id'];?>&t=<?php echo $fetpro['productname'];?>&Width=626 &Height=436 &Toolbar=0 &Status=0"><img src="images/facebook.jpg" /></a></body>
```

plz help me where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is the old method for sharing content. Use [this plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) to allow users to share content from your site...
For facebook to extract the correct image and title to preview your website read this help page about [open graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)... It shows you there exactly what meta-tags you have to place on your site so that facebook can create the correct preview.

Taken from [open graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
               a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
               threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
               weapons."/>
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: I'm now using the new format only the first image is shared? So I have added 10 images with the same tag only different url <meta property="og:image" content="url1"> in the header. Only the first is shown, any tips?